# Keeping track of changes in Google Calendar

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, google-api

I am trying to make a feature in my website, where users can create a meeting, and then have that meeting sent to various people who they added. I am sending the event in ics format, so that any calendar application can import it. The plan is when a user changes an event on their personal calendar, that change gets sent back to the company's email address, as an ics attachment, where the server reads the email, and updates the event in our database to reflect the user's changes. It is important we stay updated with when the user has planned their meeting.

This works on outlook calendar for example, and our database gets updated to reflect the user's changes. However due to the fact that when an event gets added to Google Calendar, the attendees get removed, there seems to be no way for us to be notified of if the user moves the meeting for example on Google Calendar. According to my research Google always removes the attendees when importing an ics file.

Is anyone aware of anyway for our company's email address to either remain in the attendee list without being auto removed, or for Google Calendar to inform us without asking permission from the user that the event has been changed?